# Incorrect check of SIP version during PyQt installation

Tags: macos, pyqt, osx-leopard, python-sip

I have been trying to install PyQt on my mac (OSX 10.6.8), but I still having this problem:

When I try to install PyQt-mac-gpl-4.9.6, I get this

```
Error: This version of PyQt requires SIP v4.14.2 or later.
```

The weird thing is that when I want to check for sip version on the console and write

```
sip -V
```

,I get the correct version: 4.14.2

I have checked my PATH but non of the online tips that I have found have helped me. How do I fix this?

Comment: did you try to reinstall SIP?

Comment: yes, I have uninstall sip and re-installed, but same error, thanks for your time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend checking to see if you have sip installed in different locations, with the newer version being in a path that is not at the head of your `PATH`.

```
mdfind -name sip | grep '/bin/'
```

This should tell you all of the sip binaries on your computer. Check the version of all of them, and then make sure that path is at the front of `PATH`

What it could actually be, regardless of it seeming like you only have one sip, is a leftover `.pyc` file that is getting picked up before your intended sip. Try this to confirm:

```
$ python
>>> import sipconfig
>>> print sipconfig
```

This will tell you where it is finding sipconfig. If it looks like the wrong spot, or if you check it and all that is left is the `pyc` file, remove it. Then your newer sip should be found properly.

Comment: Correct @jdi
I had the same problem and it turned out to be a pyc file that had been left behind from previous installation

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue after installing sip 4.14.2 over a previous version of 4.13.1 on Mac OSX 10.7.4 and Python 2.7.  Strangely, the version of sip from the command line was different from the version from the Python sipconfig module.

```
$ sip -V
4.14.2
$ python -c "import sipconfig; print sipconfig.version_to_string(sipconfig.Configuration().sip_version)"
4.13.1
```

I ran through the install again, this time with running the install step as 'sudo make install' and the two versions matched at 4.14.2 and the PyQt instal was successful.

```
$ cd ~/Downloads/sip-4.14.2/
$ python configure.py
$ make
$ sudo make install
```